# Declaring a single type - "using" equivalent for single type

Tags: typescript

In C# I can do this:

```
using IAnyType = App.Namespace.Types.IAnyType ;
class BaseClass : IAnyType { }
```

Is there a Typescript equivalent?

```
//BAD:
import IDialogOptions = App.Widgets.Interfaces.IDialogOptions; //A module cannot be aliased as a non-module type
class BaseClass implements IDialogOptions { }

//BAD:     
declare var IDialogOptions: App.Widgets.Interfaces.IDialogOptions;
class BaseClass implements IDialogOptions { } //The name IDialogOptions does not exist in the current context
```

The closest I can get is:

```
import Interfaces = App.Widgets.Interfaces;
class BaseDialog implements Interfaces.IDialogOptions { }
```

It's not ideal to use this long name every time I need to use this interface. I guess it's not all the bad but I was wondering if there's a better?

Comment: The suggestion for this feature is to be found here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2956

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually prefer your original solution over the alternatives:

```typescript
import Interfaces = App.Widgets.Interfaces;
class BaseDialog implements Interfaces.IDialogOptions { }
```

Without having the alias (`Interfaces`) you could get naming collisions - which if you have ever had to handle with `using` statements is a real pain as you end up using an alias or using the full namespace.

```csharp
using myAlias = App.Namespace.Types;
```

At least having an alias for all modules you import means this won't be an issue.

Comment: I agree with your point although I still think it should be an option as long as the compiler will catch the name collisions. Thanks

Comment: You never know - the language is still in beta and they are accepting suggestions over at http://typescript.codeplex.com/ - so it might be added in the future if it gets suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I too am annoyed that you can't alias things the way you might expect. What I've done is ended up using abbreviated 'namespaces' to keep things short.

```
import RSV = module("views/researchSectionView")
var r = new RSV.ResearchSectionView();
```

Comment: Yes, that was another alternative I was aware of but didn't like. Steve has a good point though. +1